# Seven seas, dynasties and forests

Tags: shloka, reference-request

Below [shloka](http://shlokam.org/saptarnava/):

> सप्तार्णवः सप्त कुलाचलाश्च सप्तर्षयो द्वीप वनानि सप्त ।
> भूरादि कृत्वा भुवनानि सप्त कुर्वतु सर्वे मम सुप्रभातम् ।।

> The seven seas, seven dynasties, seven rishis, seven isles and forests, the seven worlds like the earth – may all of them make mine a good morning.

Which seven seas, dynasties and forests are mentioned here?

Comment: Where is this from?

Comment: I think it's a Shubhashitam maybe. @Aupakrana Abhibhaa

Comment: **Saptarnava** - lavanoda (salty ocean), ikshurasoda (sugarcane juice), Suroda (liquor), Ghritoda (ghee ocean),   Dadhioda (curd), Kshiroda (milk), Svaduda (fresh water);   **saptadvipa**- Jambudvipa, Plakshadvipa, Salmalidvipa, Kusadvipa, Kraunchadvipa, Sakadvipa, Pushkaradvipa; **saptarshis** (current Manvantara) - Jamadagni, Gautama, Kashyapa, Vasishtha, Vishvamitra, Atri, Bharadvaja. **Seven worlds**- bhu, bhuvah svah, maha, jana, tapa, satya. Most likely 7 kulas are 7 main gotras from the original Saptarshi (Marichi, Vasishtha, Atri, Pulastya, Pulaha, Bhrigu, Angiras)

Comment: @archit makes sense. Kula may be incorrectly translated to dynasties. Thank you. In Gotras, kashyapa is not one of the main?

Comment: @Shebbar Kashyapa is the main not Marichi but I said Marichi because Kashyapa ultimately descended from him and Marichi didn’t have other kids. One more: similarly Kaushika (Vishwamitra) is a an important gotra but he ultimately comes from Atri therefore...

Answer (score 2):

The seven oceans surround the seven continents as given

> **Brahma Purana Chapter 16:11-12**. O brahmins, there are seven continents viz—Jambū, Plakṣa, Śālmala, Kuśa, Krauñca, Śāka and Puṣkara. *These are encircled by seven oceans, the briny ocean (lavanoda), sea of the sugarcane juice (iksurasa), wine (suroda), ghee (ghrta), curds (Dadhi), milk (kshiroda) and sweet water (jala).*

The *Kulacala* is a sanskrit word which means seven mountains and is wrongly translated here as seven dynasties.

**Bhīṣma Parva, Chapter 9, Verse 11**

[image]

> The seven mountains of *Bhratavarsha* also known as *kulaparvatas* are named as follows: Mahendra, Malaya, Sahya, Śuktimān, Ṛkṣavān, Vindhya, Pāriyātra.